# How do I get text to align to around a picture on a website

Tags: html, image, css

I'm working on a personal website highlighting my certifications on a personal website. Part of the ToS to use the images is to place a TM in the upper right corner of each image. I'm having trouble getting the text to align where it needs to be.

This is what I have:

HTML

```
<div id="imagesMain"> 
        <img src="aplus.png"> TM
        <img src="network.png"> TM
        <img src="security.png"> TM
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#imagesMain {
 padding: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#imagesMain img {
    height: 100px;
     width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The end result gives this...

[image]

What I'd like is all images in a tight line and a small "TM" in the proper place. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wrap each image into separate div and then make that div position relative and put tm in p tag after that make that p position absolute and then you can move it top:0 right:0 to make it appear on top right side.

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. It would also be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your images with a `span` and then use a pseudo to add the TM in upper right corner

```css
#imagesMain {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#imagesMain span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#imagesMain span::after {
  content: 'TM';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
}
#imagesMain img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesMain">
  <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00"></span>
  <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00"></span>
  <span><img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which will put the logo on the upper right corner for you, here I have used some dummy images you can replace them with your images.

```css
#imagesMain div{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
#imagesMain div > p{
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
  right:0;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="imagesMain"> 
  <div>        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/1"> <p>TM</p></div>
<div>  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/2"> <p>TM</p></div>
<div>  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/3"> <p>TM</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap images and TM-text in a DIV, make that `position: relative`, put the TM-text into t span, make that `position: absolute` with `top: 0; right: 0;`. For details, see my snippet below.

```css
#imagesMain {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#imagesMain img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

#imagesMain div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#imagesMain span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesMain">
  <div><img src="aplus.png"><span class="x">TM</span></div>
  <div><img src="network.png"><span class="x">TM</span></div>
  <div><img src="security.png"><span class="x">TM</span></div>
</div>
```